# Hide scrollbars in Quasar/Vue - overflow hidden not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar/VueJS for development. How can I remove the outermost scrollbar (this is for the actual body of the page).

So annoyed that I have already tried putting `overflow:hidden` everywhere but it is still there.
Since I have a scrollbar for my sidebar, I just dont want another scrollbar to be beside it, as it can be confusing for the user. As you can see, I am working on adding another scrollbar just beside the actual body of the page.

How can I get rid of the outermost scrollbar?

[image]

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/kzaiwo/pen/bGVrweM?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fquasar.dev%2Flayout%2Fdrawer

Comment: Have you tried the Css classes `no-scroll` and `no-scrollbar` on the outer page? See 'Scroll-related' in [this quasar docs section](https://quasar.dev/style/other-helper-classes).

Comment: Yes, I did.. I have updated my codepen with the ```no-scroll``` and ```no-scrollbar``` classes now

Comment: Empirically you suppress the scrollbar with selecting the dom element `.q-layout-container > .absolute-full > .scroll` and setting the `overflow-y` property to `hidden`. That has visual side effects, eg. the width of the header. While these effects can probably be compensated for, it is an unsatisfactory approach ...

Answer (score 2):

Working with Quasar, checkout the docs, more specific this class: no-scrollbar. apply this on the element of concern.

Adding the following to your main styling will make the scroll bar go away without losing the scroll functionality:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}
```

Be aware that this will not work for firefox and IE. More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

```
.scroll {
overflow: hidden;}
```

Add this class to your css

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this, but sadly, while the scrollbar is gone, I am not able to scroll anymore even using my mouse scroll button :( I can only scroll by clicking and dragging the actual (other) scroll bar

Comment: .scroll.relative-position.fit.hide-scrollbar { overflow: scroll
} add this class

Answer (score 1):

```html
<q-layout container>
```

Remove container from q-layout.

```html
<q-layout>
```

https://quasar.dev/layout/layout#qlayout-api

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scrollbar without loosing the scroll behavior with css...

```
/* Hide scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

This works on chrome for sure, probably on Safari aswell, not sure (probably not) if IE and Firefox.